# Secondary Power Distribution Unit (SPDU) vs DC-DC converter?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter

While I was researching DC-DC converters, I saw something called a "Secondary Power Distribution Unit (SPDU)". According to the author this unit is mainly used in armored vehicles.

I researched on the internet, but I couldn't find what it is and why they are used. I have some questions about it:

1. What is an SPDU and why is it used in armored vehicles?
2. What is the difference between an SPDU and a regular DC-DC converter?

Here is one product that is called an SPDU, but the page itself does not contain any useful information:

[SPDU product](https://www.ametekpds.com/products/power-distribution/dc-secondary-power-dist-unit)

Comment: Speak more to "the person".

Comment: Cannot find him. I wonder if there is such a thing.

Comment: Actually I found that there is such a thing. But they were like datasheets of the products. So I couldn't really get what it is and what is the difference of it from a DC-DC converter.

Comment: Remember that this is a question and answer site and not a forum. If you have anything to add to your question to make it more accessible for an answer, please edit it with the appropriate information.

Comment: Well there are 2 appropriate questions. Let me repeat that again: What is SPDU and what is the difference between SPDU and a regular DC-DC converter. How comes these are not the questions that are not accessible for any answer?

Comment: Why aren't you speaking with the person who told you this? What is it in the linked site that is so problematic to your understanding? Why something may or may not be used in an armoured vehicle is down to the choice of the designer. It isn't a DC-DC controller as far as I can tell.

Comment: How can I speak with the person, I have seen it over the internet. Information in the linked site is not really problematic but again that is not really informative. It looks like a unit that distribute power and that has a circuit breaker unit. So I wanted to learn more about this unit.

Comment: You said in your question: *according to the person this unit is mainly used in armored vehicles*..... so speak to the person! Communicate with the person!

Comment: Look that is a unit that is being used in the industry. Why I cannot ask an information about a device that is being actively used in an industry in here? Why I cannot use here to ask my question, when I state that I heard some unit from some stranger over internet "which is being used in industry". Stop acting as I am talking about an imaginary thing, or "he" is the only one knows anything about this device.

Comment: I said many times I cannot find that person. So that is  meaningless you are keep saying that "speak to him". If I could, I wouldn't ask it in here anyways.

Comment: Compare that product listing with another power supply. It contains lots fo useful information.

Comment: @BrianDrummond This unit only distributes power right? It does not look that is making any voltage changes. So it is something like a unit increases the number of input voltage ( such as one 18 V to ten 18 V) without any power degradation.

Comment: For a suitable definition of "only". You make it sound like a bit of wire. But... "Designed to provide circuit and wiring protection, our SPDU ...  The system has configurable arc-fault protection, pulse width modulation, remote load power control, load power monitoring, automated load shedding and other prognostic and diagnostic maintenance activities." And ... "Ability to modulate outputs for utility control (speed, lighting, heating)". That's quite a lot really.

Comment: Then speak to someone else at that company. If nobody will talk with you (on email for example) then don't rely on them for information and forget about trying to figure this out with any level of confidence. I mean if I was super uber helpful and kind (not today unfortunately) I'd have to do exactly what I suggest so, why don't you do it. Talk with them.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes, What I tried to mean "main usage of the unit" by using "only". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Andyaka Will do that thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPDUs *can* contain DC/DC converters, but don't have to; it is not their main purpose to convert power.

SPDUs' functionalities differ, but their main purpose is simplifying and monitoring power connections. Among others, planes and the more complicated military vehicles use them "to save weight, space, and cost by eliminating wires, circuit breakers and utility control boxes" and make the power system more reliable and robust. Some also monitor the power system, do diagnostics, and take action when something goes wrong (re-route power, switch to back-up power, etc.).

You can read about them [here](http://www.tc.faa.gov/its/worldpac/techrpt/tc13-19.pdf) in more detail; there's even an executive summary.